# Retrieve data of child of unknown parent ID - Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase database like shown in the image.

I want to get all the data highlighted in GREEN. But I don't know keys highlighted in RED.

What should be the JavaScript Code for this?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This would log all phone numbers:

```
var usersRef = firebase.database().ref("users");
usersRef.on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.child("phoneno").val());
});
```

Note that the Firebase [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start) and [Codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/) cover this and a lot more. I highly recommend you spend some time on those, to become more familiar with Firebase.

If you want to print all phone numbers once, you can do so with:

```
var usersRef = firebase.database().ref("users");
usersRef.once("value", function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(userSnapshot) {
    console.log(userSnapshot.child("phoneno").val());
  });
});
```

This specific case is covered in the documentation on [listening for value events on a collection of data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events).

Comment: Yes, I know this method. I don't want to add a listener. I want to read the data once. :)

Comment: Reading data once still requires a listener. The only difference is pretty much `usersRef.on(...`.