# Retrieving child value of unknown parent Firebase, AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic3, angularfire

I have basic project on Firebase, AngularJS.

```
    {
  "users" : {
    "X3IuXTMi9RgOLMKBoqPJtB1JGGQ2" : {
      "profile" : {
        "firstName" : "test",
        "lastName" : "5",
        "username" : "test5"
      }
    },
    "poPg2BfHA1gq3qtXNLbuw4X2Zt23" : {
      "profile" : {
        "firstName" : "test3",
        "lastName" : "asdfg",
        "username" : "test3"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

i want to add users by username basically. when type username on alertprompt(ionic) and click add, it will find target username and get uid on its parent. and it will write data on "users/$targetuid/friendrequests/$senderuid"

my closest search result was that: [Retrieve data of child of unknown parent ID - Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45506872/retrieve-data-of-child-of-unknown-parent-id-firebase)

but i cant use any .ref codes;

```
Cannot read property 'ref' of undefined
```

i just can use FirebaseObjectObservable, what im i doing wrong ? why cant i use

```
firebase.database().ref
```

or any like this code based on .ref command?

basically cant do anything here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write

im am sort of new on coding, so if its easy or funny dont laugh much. thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

I can see two solutions here:

1) Create a usernameToUserid map: on firebase create a new resource usernameToUserid, ike below:

```
{
  "users" : {
    "X3IuXTMi9RgOLMKBoqPJtB1JGGQ2" : {
      "profile" : {
        "firstName" : "test",
        "lastName" : "5",
        "username" : "test5"
      }
    },
    "poPg2BfHA1gq3qtXNLbuw4X2Zt23" : {
      "profile" : {
        "firstName" : "test3",
        "lastName" : "asdfg",
        "username" : "test3"
      }
    }
  },
  "usernameToUserid: {
    "test5": "X3IuXTMi9RgOLMKBoqPJtB1JGGQ2",
    "test3": "poPg2BfHA1gq3qtXNLbuw4X2Zt23"
  }
}
```

This way you can retrieve the userId and then the user profile with the username.

2) Retrieve all users and search locally for username, terrible idea.

Comment: nice idea! but how can i retrieve uid data from "usernameToUserid/" i cannot use any features of firebase.database() function why its not like on the web

Comment: to retrieve the uid, after receiving the username from the "add friend" alert input, you should query usernameToUserid/username, that will return the uid. I don't understand what problem you're having with firebase, in Ionic it should work exactly the same as web. Have you configured it properly using this https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start ?